# MySQL запрос отправляется не полностью

Tags: php, mysql, запрос

Вот кусочек из файла php обработчика формы:

```
//--Отправка голосования в БД

$title = $_REQUEST['Заголовок'];
$desc = $_REQUEST['Описание'];
$vis = $_REQUEST['Видимость'];
$date = date('l jS \of F Y H:i');

$query = "
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

INSERT INTO `Голосования` VALUES (
'$vote_id',
'0',
'$title',
'$desc', 
'$type',
'$date',
'$vis',
'На рассмотрении',
'0');
";
echo $query; 

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("<b>Ошибка:</b> " . 
mysqli_error($link)); 

mysqli_free_result($result);
```

`echo` выводит весь запрос верно, но `mysqli_error` все равно возвращает ошибку вида:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO 
`Голосования` VALUES ( '3', '0', 'Заголовок',' at line 3
```

Запрос составлен верно (проверял в консоли phpMyAdmin на локалке) значит ошибка происходит из-за того, что часть запросу попросту не доходит. Как это исправить?

Comment: А библиотека поддерживает мультизапросы? Если да - не надо ли это явно разрешить в настройках?

Comment: Исправил `mysqli_query` на `mysqli_multi_query` и ошибка ушла, спасибо за подсказку)